# Understanding わかんないこと言うんじゃないのっ

Tags: grammar, contractions, nominalization

> A) 「ちがうっ、量が肝心だよォ」
>   A) That's wrong. Quantity is vital.
>   B)「わかんないこと言うんじゃないのっ」
>   B) Didn't I say that I don't understand.

The context is that A is trying to get B to buy more stuff. B explains that quantity is not important.

I think my translation of the second sentence must be wrong. Neither A nor B say that they don't understand anything. Furthermore, why is こと used rather than just と? And, why is it わかんない rather than わからない? Is that just a standard contraction? Also I'm guessing there's a を that's been omitted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start with the easiest part, 「わか**ん**ない」 is just the Kanto colloquial pronunciation of 「わか**ら**ない」, and I will use the dictionary form in my explanation.

It appears to me that you are thinking of the "***other***"「わからない」, which is the negative form of the ***verb*** 「わかる」, are you not?

The 「わからない」 in the context in question needs to be understood and treated as an ***adjective***, which is why it can take 「こと」 with it.  ***It means "not sensible", "dense", "dull-witted", etc***.

> 「Verb in Dictionary Form + の/ん + では/じゃ + ないの」

is a negative imperative form; therefore 「言うんじゃないのっ」 means "Don't say ~~!"

「わかんないこと言うんじゃないのっ」 thus literally means "Don't say an insensible thing!".  So all you have to do now would be to turn that into natural English.  I am in no position to give you natural English for obvious reasons, but the phrase that came instantly into my mind upon reading this question was indeed ***"Don't gimme crap!"***

> why is こと used rather than just と?

Because 「わかんない」 is used as an adjective here.  Noun 「こと」 can follow it naturally and smoothly.  Using 「と」 is impossible because the speaker is not quoting.

> Also I'm guessing there's a を that's been omitted?

Precisely.  「わか**ん**ない」 is colloquial and so is 「言う**んじゃないのっ**」.  One should reasonably expect particle omission in such speech.