Is ないの by itself used as imperative at the end of a sentence?
いやだ! けいちゃん　自分が指導者じゃないからって怒んないの! 弱いって思われちゃう!
The character is scolding her friend けいちゃん because he didn't get picked as a leader, telling him to not get mad. Is it alright to 怒んないの as an imperative here?

Does this answer your question: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/47610/9831 強く決めつけて命令する意を表す。「余計なことを言わないの」, 軽く命じるのに使う。「さっさと着替えるの」「強い子は泣かないの」 , https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/95984/9831

As for the sound change of おこらない -> おこんない, see: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/41478/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/34023/9831
